# acessing xib and classes of another project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction

okay so I have two projects one in which I have done all the UI and other where I have all background stuff..I don't want to remake the entire project as there are a lot of framerworks to be included and all that stuff. so is it possible for me to use classses from one project into another without actually like copying the class files.

any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to drag an Xcode project to an existing project. But I got to say, your question is kind of weird, how do you plan to do the integration? In any case if you plan to upload the project to the app-store you will have to refactor the code. You said that you don't want to copy the classes from one project to the other because: *"there are a lot of framerworks to be included and all that stuff."*

Adding framework to an Xcode project is one of the easiest thing you can do, it really cost you nothing. I think the best solution for you is to integrate the 2 projects into one. Goodluck :)